# Choose an element from array to maximize sum after XOR all elements in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

You are given an array A. You have to choose an element from this array say A[k] and form a new array B such that B[i] = A[i]^A[k]. (^ means bitwise XOR).
Now the score of the array would be the sum of all elements of B.
The task is to find the element with which the score of the array would be maximum.
Example-
If A = [15,11,8]
and we choose A[k] = 15 then B would be [0,4,7] (15^15=0,15^11=4,15^8=7). The score would be 0+4+7 = 11 which is the maximum we can get by choosing any element as A[k].
Another Example-
If A = [11,12,13,14,15] maximum possible score=22.
How can we solve this problem to choose an element which yields the maximum score.
How to solve this question or how to proceed with such questions?

Comment: That's not true, I tried but couldn't solve that's why asking here.

Comment: "Shows no effort" is not a valid reason for closing a question, but Yash -- the comment is pointing out that the question does not describe what you tried or didn't try, rather than stating that you didn't try anything. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions describes how to ask (and answer) homework questions on s-o.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to many xor algorithm problems is to work bit by bit. Here, if for each bit position you count the number of array elements that have that bit set (which incidentally tells you how many array elements don't have that bit set by subtracting from the array length), you have a way of quickly computing `sum(A[i] xor X)` for any `X`, by considering the part of the sum that's contributed by each possible bit. That way of computing the sum depends on the bit width of the largest number in the array, but not on the length of the array.

Once you've done that, you can simply go through the array and find the element that maximizes the sum.

If you do this right, then the algorithm is O(NW) where N is the length of the input array, and W is the smallest number such that each of the input numbers fit in a W-bit integer. And it'll use O(W) additional storage. (Typically, these algorithm problems limit the size of the inputs so they fit in an int32 or int64, so W will be 32 or 64).

Comment: once we have the array elements that have that bit set, after that can you please tell me how can we compute the sum(A[i] xor X), I am unable to follow.

Comment: Compute sum((A[i]&B) xor X) for each one-bit number B and then add them all together. You can use the already-computed counts of the number of array elements with bit B set/clear to compute these sums in O(1) time, but you might need to think to figure out how.

Comment: Understood your approach and wrote code as well. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Hi Yash, can I know the solution please